# Tweaking performance of Java's sockets

Tags: java, performance, sockets, networking

I've created a remote desktop control application. Obviously, it consists of client and server parts:

**Server:**

- Receiving mouse/keyboard actions from client;
- Sending screenshot of desktop to client.

**Client:**

- Receiving screenshot from server;
- Sending mouse/keyboard actions;

Consider sending the screenshot. When I use my home PC as a server - I end up with a 1920x1080 screenshot dimension. By using [JAI Image I/O Tools](http://download.java.net/media/jai-imageio/builds/release/1.1/) and encoding it as PNG I was able to achieve the following stats for such a big image:

1. Write time ~0.2 s; (not into socket, but into some "regular" output stream, **i. e. encode time**)
2. Read time ~0.05 s; (not from socket, but from some "regular" input stream, **i. e. decode time**)
3. Size ~250 KB;
4. Perfect quality.

As a result, according to #1 - the ideal possible FPS should be ~5.

Unfortunately, I'm not able to achieve even those ~5 FPS, not even 2 FPS. I searched for the bottleneck and found out that writing/reading to/from **socket I/O streams** takes up to ~2 s (**See appendix 1 and 2 for clarification**). Surely that is unacceptable.

I've researched the topic a bit - and added buffering of socket's I/O streams (with `BufferedInputStream` and `BufferedOutputStream`) on both sides. I've started with 64 KB sizes. This indeed improved performance. But still can't have at least 2 FPS! In addition, I've experimented with `Socket#setReceiveBufferSize` and `Socket#setSendBufferSize` and there were some changes in speed, but I don't know how exactly they behave, therefore I don't know which values to use.

Look at initialization code:

**Server:**

```
    ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket();
    serverSocket.setReceiveBufferSize( ? ); // #1
    serverSocket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(...));

    Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
    clientSocket.setSendBufferSize( ? ); // #2
    clientSocket.setReceiveBufferSize( ? ); // #3

    OutputStream outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(
            clientSocket.getOutputStream(), ? ); // #4
    InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(
            clientSocket.getInputStream(), ? ); // #5
```

**Client:**

```
    Socket socket = new Socket(...);
    socket.setSendBufferSize( ? ); // #6
    socket.setReceiveBufferSize( ? ); // #7

    OutputStream outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(
            socket.getOutputStream(), ? ); // #8
    InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(
            socket.getInputStream(), ? ); // #9
```

**Questions:**

1. Which values would you recommend (to improve performance) for all
   these cases and why?
2. Please clarify `Socket#setReceiveBufferSize` and
   `Socket#setSendBufferSize` behavior.
3. What other methods/techniques can you advise to improve performance
   of such application?
4. Skype provides good-quality real-time desktop transmission - how do they do it?

**Appendix 1:** Adding the unrolled pseudo-code of client socket reading (@mcfinnigan):

```
while(true) {
    // objectInputStream is wrapping socket's buffered input stream.
    Object object = objectInputStream.readObject(); // <--- Bottleneck (without setting proper buffer sizes is ~2 s)

    if(object == null)
        continue;

    if(object.getClass() == ImageCapsule.class) {
        ImageCapsule imageCapsule = (ImageCapsule)object;

        screen = imageCapsule.read(); // <--- Decode PNG (~0.05 s)

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                repaint();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Appendix 2:** Adding the unrolled pseudo-code of server socket writing (@EJP):

```
while(true) {
    // objectOutputStream is wrapping socket's buffered output stream.
    BufferedImage screen = ... // obtaining screenshot
    ImageCapsule imageCapsule = new ImageCapsule();

    imageCapsule.write(screen, formatName()); // <--- Encode PNG (~0.2 s)

    try {
        objectOutputStream.writeObject(imageCapsule); // <--- Bottleneck (without setting proper buffer sizes is ~2 s)
    }
    finally {
        objectOutputStream.flush();
        objectOutputStream.reset(); // Reset to free written objects.
    }
}
```

**Conclusion:**

Thanks for your answers, specially EJP - he made things a bit more clear to me. If you are like me - seeking answers on how to tweak sockets' performance you should definitely check [TCP/IP Sockets in Java, Second Edition: Practical Guide for Programmers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0123742552), especially chapter 6 "Under the Hood" which describes what happens behind the scenes of `*Socket` classes, how send and receive buffers are managed and utilized (which are primary keys to performance).

Comment: Are you sure the socket settings are your limiting factors? What kind of connection do you have between your client and your server? What is the up speed from your server?

Comment: Can you post the code where you read from the sockets on the client side?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_encoding

Comment: @Roger Lindsjö What do you you mean by "what kind of connection"? How can I measure up speed of my server?

Comment: Why are you testing for null? and continuing? Are you expecting to write a null to the `ObjectOutputStream?`

Comment: Nope, it's just for security - since I was not sure that it really stops on `readObject()` and waits until there is really something to read there. In other words, I thought that it checks and if it cannot read yet - it returns `null`.

Comment: @Haroogan I was unclear of how you deploy your client/server. If you have a 1MBit connection between them then it will physically take about 2 seconds to transfer 250KB. You could test the speed by simply fetching content from your server and measure the time it takes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> - Write time ~0.2 s;
> - Read time ~0.05 s;

These objectives are completely meaningless without consideration of the latency and bandwidths of the intervening network.

> Size ~250 KB;

Off topic. Image size is up to you, and it has no relationship to actual programming, which is the purpose of this site.

> Perfect quality.

'Perfect quality' only requires that you don't drop any bits, which you won't get anyway via TCP.

```
  serverSocket.setReceiveBufferSize( ? ); // #1
```

That sets the receive buffer size for all accepted sockets. Set it as large as you can afford, over 64k if possible.

```
socket.setSendBufferSize( ? ); // #6
```

Set this as large as you can afford, over 64k if possible.

```
    socket.setReceiveBufferSize( ? ); // #7
```

As this is an accepted socket you have already done this above. Remove.

```
    OutputStream outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(
            socket.getOutputStream(), ? ); // #8
    InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(
            socket.getInputStream(), ? ); // #9
```

The defaults for these are 8k; as long as you have decent socket buffer sizes that should be enough.

> Which values would you recommend (to improve performance) for all these cases and why?

See above.

> Please clarify `Socket#setReceiveBufferSize()` and `Socket#setSendBufferSize()` behavior.

They control the size of the TCP 'window'. It's a fairly abstruse topic but the idea is to get the size at least equal to the bandwidth-delay product of your network, i.e. bandwidth in bytes/second times delay in seconds >= buffer size in bytes.

> What other methods/techniques can you advise to improve performance of such application?

Don't futz around with sleeps and doing other tasks while sending data. Send it as fast as you can in the tightest possible loop you can arrange.

> Skype provides good-quality real-time desktop transmission - how do they do it?

Off topic and probably unknowable unless a Skype employee happens to want to give away company secrets here.

Comment: Thanks for this information. However, I have to disagree with you about image write/read times. Look into original post - I've added clarification there. These are writes/reads not into socket itself, but to "regular" I/O streams. Therefore this time shows average time required to encode/decode PNG. Think about it - I cannot send PNG faster than every ~0.2 s - no matter what is the speed of the connection; I cannot read PNG faster than every ~0.05 s - no matter what is the speed of the connection;

Comment: @Haroogan My point is that you can't read or write any faster than the network, so specifying times for each is futile.

Comment: The same goes about the size of the image - I felt like this is important for considering sizes for buffers, isn't it?

Comment: @Haroogan No, why? The only important thing is the TCP window size, which is determined by the size of the receive buffer of the receiver.

Comment: It's the opposite actually - you may tweak network - make it faster. But in general case - you can do nothing about encode/decode times of PNG. Therefore, in this case, encode/decode (write/read) times for PNG dictate the minimum transfer time, and networking has an additional (secondary) impact, which I'm currently trying to mitigate.

Comment: You say "TCP window size", OK. But, if I say that server can give maximum of 500 KB/S, then doesn't it imply that I'm able to transfer only maximum of 2 PNG images of ~250 KB per second?

Comment: @Haroogan You can tweak your network by using different providers. What the performance of image codecs has to do with Java sockets is a mystery to me. Re your window size question, the idea is to 'fill the pipe'. Read again what I said about bandwidth-delay product. You are only considering one of two dimensions.

Comment: Surely, it has nothing to do with sockets :) But, it has something to do with this specific application. Therefore, I thought that this information was worth including - so that others won't ask questions like "are you sure that the problem is in sockets?"

Comment: @Haroogan You stated in your post that you 'want to achieve the following stats for such a big image'. Specifying these targets without considering the network is completely meaningless.

Comment: It's actually "I was able to achieve the following stats" - I de facto have these stats right now. I think that somethign was misleading to you in my post, sorry about that.

Comment: OK, but, again, the numbers are meaningless without considering the performance of the network. You won't obtain LAN type performance over the Internet.

Comment: That's for sure - I've posted these numbers to indicate the maximum FPS I can get in ideal world (LAN for example, as you say). Yeah, that might be meaningless, but it shows performance of raw application (without networking) and prevents questions like "are you sure that the problem is in sockets?".

Comment: Please see appendix 1 and 2 in my original post. I've pointed where PNG read/write times are involved, and showed bottlenecks in both appendices. I hope this will clarify how PNG stats fit into the whole picture of application. Maybe you will have some suggestions on appendix 2.

Comment: What's the difference the between setting #2 and #6? In other words, does it matter if I set it on server side or client side?

Comment: @Haroogan Set the send buffer size at the side that is sending. You might also want to investigate JPG instead of PNG. You will lose a little quality but you may save a lot of space.

Comment: Both sides are sending and receiving as stated in the beginning of my post. So what should I do about that? Should there be both #2 and #6 then? About JPG - well as you know text quality suffers a lot in JPG, concerning size - it is approximately the same as PNG (from what I've tried) - so I have no reason to switch to it.

Comment: @Haroogan 'Set the send buffer size at the side that is sending' => if both sides are sending, set it at both sides.

Answer (score 8):

- If client opens new TCP connection for each image, then [TCP slow start](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slow-start) may cause the slowness. --> Use same TCP connection for all frames.
- TCP have own buffers which are used optimal way for TCP --> `BufferedOutputStream` gives sometimes benefit and some times not.
- Usually only small part of screen is changed between screenshots. --> Transfer only changed parts.

Comment: I know that #3 is a very good speed-up, but it is something that is difficult to implement - and I'm no expert in that kind of problems (that's why it will be my last consideration). #1 is of no discussion. #2 is interesting - are you sure?

Comment: #2 is incorrect according to my observations. Using buffered streams is EXTREMELY important - it provides significant performance boost for i/o operations on sockets.

Comment: @Haroogan : Ok, I will remove the #2. But remember to use flush() after writing image to BufferedOutputStream.

Comment: I'm writing `ImageCapsule` (inside it contains byte array with encoded image) into `ObjectOutputStream` which in turn wraps `BufferedOutputStream` which wraps `GZIPOutputStream` which finally wraps socket's `OutputStream` :) Therefore, I can `flush` only on `ObjectOutputStream`. But I suppose that it results in a chain of `flush` calls to respective streams in wrapping chain, doesn't it?

Answer (score 2):

I think the greatest bandwith waste will lie in the complete transfer of the desktop. You should treat this more like a film and make differential encoding of frames.

The drawback is the more complicated handling. Maybe there are some simple video codec APIs/implementations out there?

Answer (score 2):

The question is clear.
Somebody above me suggests the usage of multiple nio channels, I'd rather use multiple blocking socket (nio is not faster). However this is not improving net comm, this is parallel programming that definitely would be a good solution in your case.
Let me suggest the following

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setTcpNoDelay(boolean)

setting it to true, you'll be able to speed the socket comm up at the cost of an increase in bandwidth consumption.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at Java NIO (http://www.cs.brown.edu/courses/cs161/papers/j-nio-ltr.pdf), use more than one channel, etc.